# $g^{2k} \equiv g^i \pmod{p} \implies 2k \equiv i \pmod{p-1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why does

$$g^{2k} \equiv g^i \pmod{p}$$

imply that

$$2k \equiv i \pmod{p-1}$$

when $p$ is some prime and both $i$ and $k$ are $\in \{0, 1, \dots , p-1\}?$

Comment: There is a fairly straightforward way to argue this with group-theoretic arguments. Are you looking for a strictly number theory argument here?

Comment: It doesn't. Perhaps you want to specify that $g$ is a primitive root of $p$.